# How to display sub child pages only when on direct parent page?

Tags: wordpress

I have a pretty normal page hierarcy structure like this:

```
- Main page
- - Child page
- - Child page 2
- - Child page 3
- - - Sub child page
- - - Sub child page 2
- - Child page
- - Child page
- - - Sub child page
- Main page 2
- - Child page
...
```

When I am on any page I want to display a menu on the sidebar with all the child pages, but not the main page.
This, I can do with this set of arguments which I got from another answer:

```
<?php 
$child_of_value = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );
$depth_value = ( $post->post_parent ? 2 : 1 );
$args = array( 
        'depth' => $depth_value,
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 
        'sort_order' => 'asc',
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $child_of_value,
        'echo' => 0
);

      $children = wp_list_pages($args);
?>
```

This way, in the menu are shown all the child pages belonging to same main page. The problem is with sub child pages. I want to show them only when I'm in their direct parent page, but together with all the other pages.

So for example, if I'm in a child page without any other child it would appear like this:

```
- - Child page <---
- - Child page 2
- - Child page 3
- - Child page
- - Child page
```

while if I'm on the third, it would appear like this:

```
- - Child page
- - Child page 2
- - Child page 3 <---
- - - Sub child page
- - - Sub child page 2
- - Child page
- - Child page
```

The same would it be, then, if I'm in a sub child page, where I would show the same.
Is there any way I can achieve this modifying the arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not by just modifying the arguments, but it can be achieved through CSS. If you manipulate the depth like you're doing, it will get that depth for all links in the menu. This is fine for depth zero, but when you get to depth 1 & beyond, it will show child menus for all of those pages that have children.

Instead, here is the code to generate the menu listing all subpages of your top level page (including grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc) with all depths, which can then be hidden or shown based on the current page:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID );
    $top_parent = $post->ID;
    while( $parent_id ){
        if( $parent_id > 0 ){
            $top_parent = $parent_id;
        }
        $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $parent_id );
    }
    $args = array( 
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 
        'sort_order' => 'asc',
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $top_parent,
        'echo' => 1
    );
    $children = wp_list_pages($args);
?>
```

In your stylesheet, you can use these:

```
.page_item_has_children > .children {display: none;} /*hides the submenu*/
.page_item_has_children.current_page_item > .children,
.page_item_has_children.current_page_ancestor > .children {display: block;} /*shows the submenu for the current page or when on its subpages /*
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect and way better than I could've expected. Exactly what I needed.
For future reference I would just point out that the value of the parameter "echo" should be 0, since you're assigning the wp_list_pages result to a variable

Comment: My bad - I had set it to 1 when testing it and forgot to set it back. Glad it worked for your needs!

Comment: @Joe-NewNine - is there anyway to do exactly the same as above, BUT including the $top_parent in the side bar? Thanks!

Comment: Not automatically, but you have the top parent id and your $children variable has items wrapped in li tags, so you could do something like this: <ul><li><a href="<?php print get_permalink( $top_parent ); ?>"><?php print get_the_title( $top_parent ); ?><ul><?php print $children; ?></ul></li></ul> or something to that effect. You have what you need so you can print whatever you want here. Make sense?

Comment: @Joe-NewNine - you are a Prince among Men. Yes, makes sense, thank you kindly.